# "android javax.net.ssl.SSLException: 502 AUTH TLS OK" on HUAWEI smartphone but it works well on a SAMSUNG smartphone. Why?

Tags: java, android, ftps

I get this exception  "android javax.net.ssl.SSLException: 502 AUTH TLS OK" on HUAWEI P8 smartphone but it works well on SAMSUNG Galaxy J3 smartphone

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;

FTPSClient mFTPClient = new FTPSClient("TLS", false);

mFTPClient.connect(sFTPServer,iFTPPort) => exception android javax.net.ssl.SSLException: 502 AUTH TLS OK
```

HUAWEI P8 version[image: HUAWEI P8 version]

Samsung Galaxy J3 version[image: Samsung Galaxy J3 Version]

This command works with the SAMSUNG GALAXY J3 smartphone but does not work with the HUAWEI P8 smartphone: how can I solve it?

---

Comment: Can you find Android versions of both devices? This will help you to see, what is the difference between two environments.

Comment: A [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50868600/https-client-with-ftp-login-error-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-502-sslv23-tlsv1) seems to have been solved using `ftps.mydomain.com` instead of `ftp.mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#security-changes) security rules have changed in Android 9(API 28+), so you should use a way to permit clear traffic to connect to your server.

A simple way should be adding:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to your `<application>` tag in Manifest

You could try this way too:
Add:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

to your `<application>` tag in the app manifest and then create the XML file "network_security_config.xml" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
</network-security-config>
```

You find references [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#base-config) and a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962232/android-p-without-tls-network-security-config-cleartexttrafficpermitted-not-po)

Comment: Do you know where to create in android studio  the XML file "network_security_config.xml"  ? In which directory ?

Comment: I put it under "res/xml/", so its path will be res/xml/network_security_config.xml", then you can access to it in your manifest using "@xml/network_security_config"